# Is rotten food mutzkeh on Shabbat or can it be removed

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, muktzeh, orach-chaim

According to Halacha is rotten food considered muktzeh on Shabbat? Is there any heter for throwing out rotten food on Shabbat for smell or other inconveniences?

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/83227/

Comment: Graf shel rei is mutar